# Multiplexing Java's LinkedBlockingQueue

Tags: java, concurrency, queue

Is there a nice pattern for multiplexing multiple of Java's `LinkedBlockingQueue` instances onto one with the semantics of (efficient) blocking wait?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a nice pattern for multiplexing multiple of Java's LinkedBlockingQueue instances onto one with the semantics of (efficient) blocking wait?

I'd have one thread per input `LinkedBlockingQueue` each calling `take()` and then putting the elements into the shared output `LinkedBlockingQueue`.

Something like:

```
public void run() {
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        try {
            outputQueue.put(inputQueue.take());
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure what else to say about it.